# Problema con linux en instalación /permisos

Tags: linux

Estoy intentando instalar vmware essecials en una maquina con ubuntu y me tira siguiente error.

```
Before running VMware Tools for the first time, you need to configure it by 
invoking the following command: "/usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl". Do you want 
this program to invoke the command for you now? [yes]

sh: 1: /usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl: Permission denied
```

Comment: `sudo perl /usr/bin/vmware-config-tools.pl`

Comment: Y los permisos del archivo en cuestión, ¿ Cuáles son ?

Comment: Ya esta solucionado muchas gracias, Eduen.. por cierto no entiendo por que hay que poner perl, ¿A que se debe?