# Pantalla completa Kali Linux VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, línea-de-comandos

> Ejecuto estos comandos:
>   1. apt-get update
>   2. apt-get dist-upgrade
>   3. reboot
>   4. apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
>   y por último vuelvo a hacer reboot y me sale nada más realizar el primer comando este error:
>
> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock  - open (13: Permission denied)
>   E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
>   W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin  - RemoeCaches  (13: Permission denied)
>   W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin  - RemoeCaches  (13: Permission denied)
>   He probado también los comandos precedidos de "sudo", se ejecutan pero no funcionan, incluso tras hacer reboot varias veces.

Si alguien puede ayudarme o sabe alguna forma de poner pantalla completa lo agradecería.

Comment: yo he tenido el mismo problema pero con VMware y en mi caso usando sudo perl lo conseguí instalar, te dejo aquí mi post https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/186128/problema-con-linux-en-instalaci%C3%B3n-permisos

Comment: @tasiaylalo muchas gracias, era justamente eso, si me lo pones como respuesta en vez de como comentario te la pongo como respuesta correcta, un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba a limpiar el cache de apt http://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/10/09/how-to-clean-the-apt-cache

Answer (score 0):

No sé si ya lo arreglaste, pero desde virtualbox fíjate cuando arrancas un SO virtual: te dice *la tecla host es "x"*. No sé si por defecto es el control o <kbd>ctrl</kbd> derecho (o sea el que está abajo de la tecla <kbd>shift</kbd>); aprieta  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (derecho) + <kbd>f</kbd>, pones en modo pantalla completa con <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, lo pones agrandado pero que no ocupe todo el ancho y alto de tu pantalla y con <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> ocupa toda la pantalla pero te deja ver la barra de tareas de tu SO principal.

Answer (score -1):

Ejecutalo con sudo

1. apt-get update
2. apt-get dist-upgrade
3. sudo apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
4. reboot